# Run .exe in python with all files in directory

Tags: python, restart

I am working on an auto restart script for an exe but there are config files in the directory I need to run with the exe. If I start the exe from the actual file folder it works fine but when I use the script to run the exe it starts the exe without the configuration files. What can I add to this script to use all files in the directory?

```
import os, subprocess, time

while True:
      print("Starting process...")
      p = subprocess.Popen("C:\\Users\\my-pc\\Desktop\\process\\process.exe")
      time.sleep(7200)
      print("Terminating process...")
      p.terminate()
      time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set `cwd` parameter of Popen constructor to the working directory of the process, e.g.:

```
      p = subprocess.Popen("C:\\Users\\my-pc\\Desktop\\process\\process.exe", cwd="C:\\Users\\my-pc\\Desktop\\process")
```

You may also find useful the official documentation of [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call Popen with a "cwd" keyword argument that should pickup the configuration files.